# facebook can_upload is false except for one album

Tags: facebook-graph-api

If I query "me/albums?fields=can_upload,name" with the graph explorer I only get can_upload true for one album (from a total of 13 albums)

my permissions (from the Access Token Debugger): create_note photo_upload publish_actions publish_stream share_item status_update user_photos video_upload

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damn, got the solution.

I've initially set the permission for post visibility from that app to only me.

The album with can_upload true was only visible by me, too.

Comment: I had the same problem, and now it works for me. Thanks for publishing the answer!